# Complex Fourier Coefficients by Inspection?

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

This is the solution to a fourier series problem, of the function $sin(\omega_0t)$:

[image]

I understand how the author has used Euler's formula to split this function into two exponential terms. However, I don't understand how the coefficients were obtained.

They have used a method called inspection. However, they have also stated we can use the formula:
$$c_n=\frac{1}{T_0}\int^{T_0/2}_{-T_0/2} f(t)e^{-jn\omega_0t}\,dt$$

But what do we put in $T_0$ in this formula?
And what is the method of inspection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without any other specification than that cited we assume that we are working over a period with $-\pi \le \omega_0t \le \pi$ so $T_0 = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}$

so we are looking for an expansion:
$$
f(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{ni\omega_0 t}
$$

*inspection* generally means "just by looking at" - usually when we can directly guess the correct solution, perhaps with a quick bit of mental arithmetic. in applied situations this can save time by reducing formality, though there is always the danger of making an error through haste, or a false assumption etc.

however the fact that, knowing the expression given for the $\sin$ function, we immediately may write:
$$
f(t) = \frac1{2j}\left( e^{j\omega_0 t} - e^{-j\omega_0 t}\right) \tag{1}
$$
means inspection is quite reliable in the present case. the expression (1) **is already**  the required expansion!

if you plug it into the integral as given you will find, from the orthogonality of the functions $e^{i\omega_0t}$ over the given range, that all coefficients except $c_{-1}$ and $c_1$ evaluate to zero.

for example:
$$
c_1 = \frac{\omega_0}{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{\omega_0}}^{\frac{\pi}{\omega_0}}
 \frac1{2j}\left( e^{j\omega_0 t} - e^{-j\omega_0 t}\right) e^{-j\omega_0 t}dt \\
=\frac{\omega_0}{4\pi j}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{\omega_0}}^{\frac{\pi}{\omega_0}}
 \left( 1- e^{-2j\omega_0 t}\right)dt \\
=\frac{\omega_0}{4\pi j} \left[ t +\frac1{2 j \omega_0} e^{-2j\omega_0 t}\right]_{-\frac{\pi}{\omega_0}}^{\frac{\pi}{\omega_0}} \\
= \frac1{2j}
$$

Comment: How does one know it is already the required expansion?

Comment: well if you don't know that, then at this stage of your learning process, inspection is not a suitable method for you in this problem, and you may proceed with the more detailed calculations as i have indicated. perhaps you could try to derive $c_{-1} $ yourself, which only requires very small adjustments to the working. good luck!

Comment: I understood your working - thanks for being so specific!

Comment: glad to be of assistance! it helps me too, to go through the working, as these calculations, although not difficult, involve quite a bit of fiddly arithmetic - it is easy to make a minor error, and then have to spend time trying to find out what went wrong! ;-)

Comment: btw, re the inspection thing wrt Fourier series, what really brought it home to me was when i wanted to expand $\sin x$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$. of course $\sin x$ is already its own Fourier expansion! however a Fourier expansion of $\sin \frac{x}2$ over the same range is a different proposition! (because this function, unlike $\sin x$ or $\sin 2x$, say, is not an element of the orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$